# Why is this inequality true? $(a+b)^2\leq 2(a^2+b^2)$

Tags: calculus, inequality

Why is this inequality true? $a,b$ are real numbers.
$$
(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2\leq 2(a^2+b^2)
$$
I know $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2 \geq 0$, but then?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$(a-b)^2\geq0\\a^2-2ab+b^2\geq0\\a^2+b^2\geq2ab\\2a^2+2b^2\geq a^2+2ab+b^2\\2(a^2+b^2)\geq(a+b)^2$$

Comment: Thanks! But how did you go from $a^2+b^2\geq 2ab$ to $2a^2+2b^2\geq a^2+2ab+b^2$?

Comment: @JDoeDoe He added $a^{2} + b^{2}$ to both sides.

Comment: @JDoeDoe Exactly.

Answer (score 8):

Equivalently: $$a^2+2ab+b^2 \leq 2a^2+2b^2$$
Equivalently: $$0 \leq a^2-2ab+b^2$$
Equivalently: $$0 \leq (a-b)^2$$

This latter expression is true: squares are nonnegative.

Answer (score 5):

Because by C-S $$2(a^2+b^2)=(1^2+1^2)(a^2+b^2)\geq(1\cdot a+1\cdot b)^2=(a+b)^2$$

Answer (score 2):

(This is similar to some of the other answers,
but I haven't seen this exact form.)

$\begin{array}\\
2(a^2+b^2)-(a+b)^2
&=2(a^2+b^2)-(a^2+2ab+b^2)\\
&=a^2-2ab+b^2\\
&=(a-b)^2\\
&\ge 0\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Although this is not exactly the same, it is similar in spirit to the 1st, 2nd and the 4th one. What do you gain by posting this?

Comment: This is the way I would prove it.

Answer (score 1):

By Jensen's Inequality (*):
\begin{align}
(a+b)^2 &= 4\left(\frac{1}{2} a + \frac{1}{2}b\right)^2 \\
&\leq^{*} 4\left(\frac{1}{2} a^2 + \frac{1}{2}b^2\right)\\
&=2(a^2+b^2)
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Rewritten:

$(a+b) ^2 \le (a+b)^2+(a-b)^2 =2(a^2+b^2)$

Used : $(a-b)^2 \ge 0$

Answer (score 0):

By rearrangement

$$(a+b)^2=a^2+ab+ba+b^2\le $$

$$\le a^2+aa+bb+b^2=2(a^2+b^2)$$