# Prove $ 2\sqrt{2} \le \vert a+b+c \vert + \vert b+c-a \vert + \vert c+a-b \vert + \vert a+b-c \vert \le 4 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

> Prove that for all $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R} $ and $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1 $ the following inequalities are true:
> $$  2\sqrt{2} \le \vert a+b+c \vert + \vert b+c-a \vert + \vert c+a-b \vert + \vert a+b-c \vert \le 4 $$

I proved the right one just squaring both sides of the inequality, but I don't know how to do the left inequality.

Right side proof, first i square both sides:
$ \vert a+b+c \vert  = A; \vert b+c-a \vert =B; \vert c+a-b \vert = C;
\vert a+b-c \vert =D $
Then we get:
$ A^2+B^2+C^2+D^2+2AB+2BC+2CD+2DA+2BD+2CA \leq 16 $
Then using $2xy \leq x^2 +y^2 $, for all 6 AB type terms;
$ A^2+B^2+C^2+D^2+2AB+2BC+2CD+2DA+2BD+2CA \leq 4(A^2+B^2+C^2+D^2) = 4(4(a^2+b^2+c^2)) = 16 $

Comment: Check the so called Khinchin inequality.

Comment: This is a problem from an ongoing contest: problem 9 of the first stage of Polish Mathematical Olympiad. https://om.sem.edu.pl/static/app_main/problems/om75_1.pdf The deadline is 30 Nov.

Answer (score 2):

Initial guess for LHS, $a=b=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2},c=0$

Lemma:

Absolute value inequality, i.e.
$||a|-|b||≤|a±b|≤|a|+|b|$, [Proof-LHS](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193938/proving-absolute-value-inequalities)

Proof:

Given that $|a|+|b|\ge|a+b|$ (from Lemma),
$$   \vert a+b+c \vert + \vert b+c-a \vert \ge 2 |b+c|$$

Given that $|a|+|b|\ge|a+b|$ (from Lemma),
$$  \vert c+a-b \vert + \vert a+b-c \vert \ge 2|a| $$

$$  \vert a+b+c \vert + \vert b+c-a \vert + \vert c+a-b \vert + \vert a+b-c \vert \ge 2 |b+c| + 2 |a| $$

Given that $|a|+|b|\ge|a+b|$ (from Lemma),
$$\vert a+b+c \vert + \vert b+c-a \vert + \vert c+a-b \vert + \vert a+b-c \vert\ge 2|a+b+c|  $$

As $c = \sqrt{1-a^2-b^2}$

$$LHS \ge 2|a+b+c| \ge 2|a+b+\sqrt{1-a^2-b^2}| $$

Given that $||a|-|b||≤|a±b|$ (from Lemma),

$$LHS \ge 2||a+b|-|\sqrt{1-a^2-b^2}|| $$

To find the maximum of the right equation above for any a,b, i.e. $2||a+b|-|\sqrt{1-a^2-b^2}||$,

That is to Max $2|a+b|$ and Min $2|\sqrt{1-a^2-b^2}|$

To Min $2|\sqrt{1-a^2-b^2}|$, hence,  $\sqrt{1-a^2-b^2} = 0$, $1=a^2+b^2$,

To Max $2|a+b|$,

$$(\frac{a+b}{2})^2 \le \frac{a^2+b^2}{2}$$

[Proof for the above inequation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2168244/why-is-this-inequality-true-ab2-leq-2a2b2)

Plug in $1=a^2+b^2$ and get,

$$2|a+b| \le 2 \sqrt{2(a^2+b^2)}=2\sqrt{2}$$

Hence Max $2|a+b| = 2\sqrt{2}$.

$$LHS \ge |2|a+b|-2|\sqrt{1-a^2-b^2}|| = | 2\sqrt{2} - 0| = 2\sqrt{2} $$

Comment: This is a problem from an ongoing contest: problem 9 of the first stage of Polish Mathematical Olympiad. https://om.sem.edu.pl/static/app_main/problems/om75_1.pdf The deadline is 30 Nov. Please delete your answer.