# Show for all positive real $a, b, c$ that $\sum_{\text{cyc}} \frac{a^3}{b^2 - bc + c^2} \ge a + b + c$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Show for all positive reals $a, b, c$ that:

$$\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{a^3}{b^2-bc+c^2} \ge a + b + c$$

I tried the following AM-GM:

$$bc \le \frac{b^2+c^2}{2} \implies \sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{a^3}{b^2-bc+c^2} \ge \sum_{\text{cyc}} \frac{2a^3}{b^2 + c^2}$$

where (after some computational investigation) the inequality $\sum_{\text{cyc}} \frac{2a^3}{b^2 + c^2} \ge a + b + c$ seems to hold, however I "overshot" from here:

$$\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}} \frac{a^3}{b^2 + c^2}\right) \cdot \left(\sum_{\text{cyc}} \frac{b^2+c^2}{a}\right) \ge \left(\sum_{\text{cyc}} a\right)^2 = (a+b+c)^2$$

(by C-S), so it would suffice to show that

$$\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{\sum_{\text{cyc}} \frac{b^2 + c^2}{a}} \ge \frac{a+b+c}{2}$$

But this is not true, take for example $a = 951.52, b = 8919.16, c = 5458.66$ to see this (these values where acquired through a simple program I wrote to check for false "solutions"). Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to use Schur?

Comment: Note that $(1, 1, 0) $ is a (limiting) equality case, so naive AMGM/CS alone won't be sufficient.

Comment: @CalvinLin C-S works well? e.g., By C-S, $\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{a^3}{b^2-bc+c^2} \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} a(b^2 - bc + c^2) \ge (a^2 + b^2 + c^2)^2$, then prove $ (a^2 + b^2 + c^2)^2 \ge (a + b+ c)\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} a(b^2 - bc + c^2) $ which is true.

Comment: @RiverLi Oops, sorry. I didn't see your comment. My answer is same as yours.

Comment: @CalvinLin Would you like to reopen this question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4813122/prove-2-sqrt2-le-vert-abc-vert-vert-bc-a-vert-vert-ca-b-vert

Answer (score 4):

**Proof.**

By using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^3}{b^2-bc+c^2}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^4}{ab^2-abc+ac^2}\ge \frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2}{\sum_{cyc}bc(b+c)-3abc}.$$
Thus, we need to prove
$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2\ge (a+b+c)[(ab+bc+ca)(a+b+c)-6abc],$$
or
$$a^4+b^4+c^4+2\sum_{cyc}(bc)^2+6abc(a+b+c)\ge 2(ab+bc+ca)^2+(ab+bc+ca)(a^2+b^2+c^2)$$
It's $$a^4+b^4+c^4+abc(a+b+c)\ge \sum_{cyc}ab(b^2+a^2)$$which is Schur of fourth degree inequality.

Hence, the proof is done. Equality holds iff $a=b=c>0$ or $a=b>0; c=0$ and its permutations.

Answer (score 0):

*Remark.* It is too long for a comment.

I hope Chebyshev's inequality will help but the following idea is not complete.

We can rewrite the starting inequality as
$$\color{black}{\frac{(b+c)(2a^3-b^3-c^3)}{b^3+c^3}+\frac{(c+a)(2b^3-c^3-a^3)}{c^3+a^3}+\frac{(a+b)(2c^3-a^3-b^3)}{a^3+b^3}\ge 0.}$$
WLOG, asumming that $a\ge b\ge c.$
It's obvious that
$$\color{black}{\frac{1}{b^3+c^3}\ge \frac{1}{c^3+a^3}\ge \frac{1}{a^3+b^3}}.\tag{1}$$
Also, we consider that
$$2a^3b-b^4-bc^3+2a^3c-cb^3-c^4\ge  2b^3c-c^4-ca^3+2b^3a-ac^3-a^4$$
$$\iff 2ab(a^2-b^2)+(a^2-b^2)(a^2+b^2)+c^3(a-b)+3ac(a^2-b^2)\ge 0.$$
and
$$2b^3c-c^4-ca^3+2b^3a-ac^3-a^4\ge 2c^3a-a^4-ab^3+2c^3b-ba^3-b^4 $$

$$\iff 2bc(b^2-c^2)+(b^2-c^2)(b^2+c^2)+a^3(b-c)+3ac(b^2-c^2)\ge 0.$$
Thus, it gives
$$(b+c)(2a^3-b^3-c^3)\ge (c+a)(2b^3-c^3-a^3)\ge (a+b)(2c^3-a^3-b^3).\tag{2}$$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$, we may use Chebyshev's inequality

$$\color{black}{\sum_{cyc}\frac{(b+c)(2a^3-b^3-c^3)}{b^3+c^3}\ge \sum_{cyc}(b+c)(2a^3-b^3-c^3)\cdot \sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{b^3+c^3}\ge 0.}$$

It is equivalent to $$\sum_{cyc}(b+c)(2a^3-b^3-c^3)\ge 0\iff a^3(b+c)+b^3(c+a)+c^3(a+b)\ge 2(a^4+b^4+c^4)$$
$$\iff (a^3+b^3+c^3)(a+b+c)\ge 3(a^4+b^4+c^4).$$
The last inequality is reverse by Chebyshev's inequality.